# I'm having trouble figuring out how to access a variable outside of a nested class

Tags: c++

### The nested class can't access non-static elements that are outside of the class

---

Something is wrong with nested classes, as you can see by the code i've provided, 2 classes have been declared, the nested class `Entity` is inside the private field of the class `Game`, for some reason the nested class doesn't allow me to access the variable outside of it `map_info`.
I've only found 1 solution and it involves creating an instance of the Game class inside the Entity class.

---

```
class Game
{
private:
    std::string map_info;


    class entity
    {
    protected:
        double x, y, z;
    public:
    };
    class player : public entity
    {
    private: std::string name;
        player(std::string _name) : name(_name) {};
        void check()
        {
            /*
                this is the portion of the code that i'm having problem with
                the error: "a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object"

            */
            if (map_info != 'none')
            {
                // do stuff
            }
        }
    };

public:
    std::string Getmap() { return map_info; }
    Game() //constructor
    {
        // does stuff
    }
};
```

---

#### Here's something i tried doing

1. Declaring map_info as a static type (doesn't solve the problem)
2. Declaring an instance of the game class inside of the nested class

I've searched here for the same problem but the results don't fit my original code, however there might be a slight chance that i've missed something and if so please send the link.

It's my first question in this website so give as much feedback as you can, even the slightest is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You cannot directly access members of the outer class, you'll need a parameter providing the instance.

Comment: `player` needs to know which instance of `Game` to get `map_info` from. This knowledge does not come automatically. There is no implicit connection between a `player` instance and a `Game` instance.

Comment: Imagine you have an object of class `entity` outside of any instance of class `game` What variable would the `entity` be referencing then?
The compiler does not know you are not planing to do that. The `entity` objects will need to somehow know which instance of `game` they should be referencing.

Comment: Do you really need to have the class(es) nested?  Having separate classes resolves this issue.  Also, separate (not nested) classes increases the reusability.

Comment: `map_info` is a member of your class `Game`.  There must be a `Game` object for there to be a `map_info`.  This code never creates or makes any mention of a `Game` object, therefore there is no `map_info`.

Comment: I think you are confusing nested classes with aggregation. Having nested classes does _not_ mean that the parent class magically includes an instance of each nested class. It also does _not_ mean that a child class can only exist as part of the parent class. It's just a matter of declaration.

Comment: Declaring the entity class outside of the game class isn't a bad idea, it breaks some things in the main but i can handle it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't works as you want. Nested class is just class-member of your Game class, which can be accessed as `Game::NestedName` if it's public, and cannot be accessed not in class if it's private. For example

```cpp
#include <vector>

class Game
{
public:
    Game(){};
    void spawnNewPrivateEntity(double x, double y, double z)
    {
        private_entities.push_back(PrivateEntity{x, y, z}); //access to private member PrivateEntity is ok
    }
    struct PublicEntity { double x, y, z; }; //public nested struct, can be accessed from everywhere
    void spawnNewPublicEntity(PublicEntity entity)
    {
        public_entities.push_back(entity);
    }
private:
    struct PrivateEntity { double x, y, z; };   //private nested struct, can be used only inside this class or friend members
    std::vector<PrivateEntity> private_entities = {};
    std::vector<PublicEntity> public_entities = {};
}


int main()
{
    auto en = Game::PublicEntity{0.0, 9.0, 1.9}; //works
    auto en2 = Game::PrivateEntity{0.0, 0.0, 0.0}; //doesn't work: this struct is private member of Game class
}
```

You can make something like this:

```cpp
class Game
{
public:
    Game(std::string map_info): map_info(map_info)
    {};
    std::string getMapInfo() { return map_info; }
private:
    std::string map_info;
};

class Entity
{
public:
    Entity(Game *game): game(game)
    {};
    void check()
    {
        if (game->getMapInfo() != "none") { /*some code*/ }
    };
private:
    Game *game;
}
```

Comment: `Nested class is just class which could be use only inside of your Game class` nested classes can be also used outside of that class. The access qualifier can prevent the access to it, but that has nothing to do with the class being nested.